# Recommendations for installing OSSIM

Tags: ids, hardware, siem

I'm an apprentice in web security and I was assigned with the task of researching about [OSSIM](https://www.alienvault.com/open-threat-exchange/projects). *Bear with my infinite ignorance* as I take my questions to the stack exchange gurus.

**What I know so far:**

- It's free and and open source
- Once installed security administrators can easily observe all risk related processes
- It features many software components that aid in the recolection of data, these are used for vulnerability assesments, as IDS, HIDs and others.

  **What I don't know:**
- The Physical hardware I need.  I was told I would need 3 network cards (NIC). Is this true? please explain. Also I would like to know how much processing power, storage and RAM I will need.
- Will the number of Internet service providers (ISPs) be of importance
  when the hardware selection process take place?  We currently have 2
  different ISPs for different services.
- Will 1 computer with OSSIM be enough to manage security events from
  about 5 websites of medium traffic and a couple of internal systems? 
  We intend to set up a monitoring station with at least 2 physical
  monitors to ease the monitoring task.

***Kind regards***

Comment: For the types of questions you are asking, it would be best if you installed it and tested.

Comment: Alienvault is the paid version of OSSIM so it may also be useful to look over their documentation as the steps are often similar or identical.

Answer (score 1):

This question is likely going to get flagged since it is vendor specific however I will take some time to answer your questions using a security approach.

*It's free and and open source* - there is a cost associated with learning any tool and implementing it properly. There is also a cost associated with support. At crunch time, using an open source model, you're off on your own dealing with the issue. This means, finding the right forum for help, email list, etc.

*Once installed security administrators can easily observe all risk related processes* - Once installed, all it knows is what you configured it to do it. These devices take a lot of thought on placement, what it is you want to observe, why you want to observe it. This portion is done with a risk assessment: "What are you trying to protect, and why?"

*It features many software components that aid in the recolection of data, these are used for vulnerability assesments, as IDS, HIDs and others.* - these devices perform differently. This particular one uses agents for monitoring (OSSEC, Snare, etc), which means you need to go to each individual machine, configure them to talk with the central server.

**Now on to the things you need help with:**

> The Physical hardware I need. I was told I would need 3 network cards
>   (NIC). Is this true? please explain. Also I would like to know how
>   much processing power, storage and RAM I will need.

No one is going to be able to help you with this question. No one can know the intricacies of your network, how much bandwidth is used, how many events/logs need to be processed.

> Will the number of Internet service providers (ISPs) be of importance
>   when the hardware selection process take place? We currently have 2
>   different ISPs for different services.

Another question no one will be able to answer. Do you need failover capabilities? Do you need HIGH AVAILABILITY capabilities? There are too many questions for anyone to guess.

> Will 1 computer with OSSIM be enough to manage security events from
>   about 5 websites of medium traffic and a couple of internal systems?
>   We intend to set up a monitoring station with at least 2 physical
>   monitors to ease the monitoring task.

Another question no one will be able to answer and anyone doing so is doing a disservice to you in doing so.